# CPU fan restarts after power and PC not booting to bios

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, fan

I've browsed for other similar threads and I haven't got my desired answer because  **symptoms were different** in a way, though **I still tried** the suggested actions for troubleshooting, still haven't satisfied me and fixed my problem.

I'll try to keep this simple as much as possible.

---

PC was working for few weeks after it was custom built by me, then 3 days ago it started **not to boot up**, this was easily fixed just by restarting using the restart button, or a power drain restart.

Now, can't seem to fix it with a restart. 
**Key points:**

- **CPU fan turns on, then off after 2-3 secs, then on again.**  then just continues on like that. (No loops happening, only CPU fan resets not other fans)
- **HDD LED light is not turning on** in front of the case
- **TRIED to boot at least up to BIOS with minimal parts only** (PSU, CPU w/ fan, 1 RAM (tried both slots), and a keyboard)
- **TRIED re-seating / cleaned everything including cpu with thermal paste replaced**, also checked the cpu pins / RAM teeth , all good and clean.
- **TRIED bios reset**, no good, battery is new
- **CHECKED mobo for short circuit causes**, none
- **CHECKED loose/damaged/disconnected PSU wires** all intact
- **DID the paperclip test** just to be sure PSU is working, and it is.

What could be the culprit here? Since I tried booting with minimal parts, Problem now only lies within the **PSU, MOBO, CPU, RAM**

Pretty unlikely because all parts are new and has warranty but I'm trying to find out because maybe it's just some **Minor** stuff that I've missed out and I won't have the hassle of sending this back and waiting for months just because of **maybe** a small thing or something that **I** can fix.

---

Here's my rig:

- **MOBO:** Gigabyte GA-A320M-S2H DDR4
- **CPU:** AMD APU A10-9700k
- **RAM:** (2x4GB) Hyperx 8GB DDR4 2400MHz
- **HDD:** WD Green 500GB
- **GPU:** Palit GTX960 DDR5 128 bit 1 Gb
- **PSU:** Trigon Generic 700w
- **AVR:** Standard 3 Socket 220v AVR

Comment: Honestly it sounds like a PSU issue

Comment: So it doesn't boot at all now, just spins up fans & stays black? The MB could've gone bad - seems to happen a lot. You already said where the problem must be, so swap/test parts until what's left works. Or maybe your reset or power button itself is shorting out, try swapping  / unplugging them after starting.

Comment: Thank you for the your suggestion,IT WAS THE MOTHERBOARD. Turns out it was a motherboard capacitor overload. once capacitor was bulged. Probable cause of it was a voltage spike maybe I should also replace my AVR.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the RAM settings in BIOS, that CPU has max 2400Mhz, if BIOS has turned that down then it may think its bad or incompatible.

It's more than likely the PSU if there's no error beeps (If you have a motherboard speaker?) That would give better indication of the problem.

If you can; [test the PSU voltages](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-manually-test-a-power-supply-with-a-multimeter-2626158)

Comment: OP cannot boot up to BIOS. Read the question.

Comment: Thank you for the your suggestion, I have solved it by replacing the motherboard. Turns out it was a motherboard capacitor overload. once capacitor was bulged. Probable cause of it was a voltage spike maybe I should also replace my AVR. Thanks guys, Will leave this thread for reference of others that might experience this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the your suggestion, I have solved it by replacing the **motherboard**. Turns out it was a **motherboard capacitor overload**. once capacitor was bulged. Probable cause of it was a **voltage spike** maybe I should also replace my **AVR**. Thanks guys, Will leave this thread for reference of others that might experience this.